# Making UIView Scrollable without UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

Basically, what I'm trying to do is make the normal UIView scrollable (no UIScrollView). When my app changes orientation from portrait to landscape, the content that falls below the bottom boundary becomes inaccessible. When I tried to use UIScrollView, I still couldn't access the content below the bottom boundary and the ScrollView didn't resize to follow the constraints I set for it.

Can someone help me make a UIView scrollable?

Comment: The solution probably isn't to avoid using a `UIScrollView` but rather to _correctly_ use the scroll view. Your constraints obviously aren't set properly.

Comment: I second Stonz2's comment. If you really want to make your own scroll view, it's done by manipulating the container view's bounds rectangle. Setting it's origin to something other then zero offsets the location of all contained subviews. But managing the pan gesture and animations and all really isn't worthwhile if you only need a regular scroll view.

Comment: Also agreeing with Stonz2 - UIScrollView is what you need. Perhaps describe how you are using UIScrollView and what the problems are as a new question.Welcome to SO.

Comment: After searching for a solution to my constraints problem, I found the solution. I didn't know I would have to set the constraints programmatically. Thank you to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a UIView scrollable but not in a conventional way. As [@colinrf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736683/colinrf) said, that's what a UIScrollView is for. But, for example, you can make a UIView twice the height of the screen, then subtract and add the `Y` value of the `Rect` in accordance with the `UITouch` movements. For instance, if the touch location (delta if you want) is moving negative from middle of the screen to the top, move the `Y` value negatively as well. You can do it by `UIGuestureSwipe` too.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make a UIView scrollable. That's what UIScrollView is for. However if you are using storyboards you can try to add constraints to the view so when you rotate the device the content remains inside the viewable area. Sounds like you already have some constraints setup so I would just play around with them. Sometimes it can take some tweaking to get them right.